# average from three numbers with different weight

Tags: c

Why does output equal zero in this code?
Number 1 with weight of 2, number two with weight of 3 and number three with weight of 5. I can not understand why output = 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    float A ,B, C ,MEDIA=0 ;
    scanf("%f%f%f",&A ,&B,&C);
    MEDIA+=1/2*A + 1/3*B + 1/5*C;
    printf("MEDIA = %.1f", MEDIA );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your factors are calculated with integer division...

Comment: With integers, the result of `1/n` is always zero. You should try `0.5*A` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MEDIA+=1/2*A + 1/3*B + 1/5*C;

Because `1/2`, `1/3` and `1/5` will be evaluated as 0. Since they are integers.
Either write

`1.0/2`, `1.0/3` and `1.0/5` instead. So the compiler will know to treat the result as `float`.

Or

```
MEDIA+=A/2 + B/3 + C/5;
```

P.S.

Maybe I am wrong but if I understood correctly what you wrote at the description then I think your calculation of the weighted average is incorrect. It should be something like

(A*2 + B*3 + C*5)/10